# doWithDynamicMethods not being Called

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

When I create a production war (grails war --nojars) my doWithDynamicMethods is not being called in a production environment. The code works in the dev env (ie grails run-app)

Here is some of my code:

PDFFormsGrailsPlugin.groovy (in PDFForms (plugin) directory) :-

```
 def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx ->
  println "Adding renderPDFForm to controller";

  for (controllerClass in application.controllerClasses) {
   updateControllers controllerClass.metaClass
  } 
    }
```

BuildConfig.groovy (in Application using Plugin) :-

```
grails.plugin.location.'pdff-orms' = "../PDFForms"
```

We are using Grails 1.3.5 on Windows XP, The Build is called from STS 2.3.3.CI-R5462-B20

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the plugin is referenced in your grails.xml.

Read this [Nabble thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-1-3-4-and-inline-plugins-td2318927.html)

And this [jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6601)

P.S. Why not you upgrade to grails 1.3.7 at least?!